# I want my y-axis scaling to ignore one data series in my ECharts chart

Tags: echarts

I have an EChart with a few data series. I would like the y-axis to scale based on some of those series, but ignore others.

i.e.

If I have the data

```
| x | A  | B    |
|----------------
| 0 | 10 | 1    |
| 1 | 20 | 10   |
| 2 | 30 | 100  |
| 3 | 40 | 1000 |
```

I'd like the y-axis on my chart to scale to include all the values from A (i.e. show from 10 to 40) but not scale to include the values of B. In this example I'd like the graph of B to shoot up off the top of the chart.

Is there a configuration value I can set on a data series to tell the axis scaling to ignore its values (or any other configuration to make this happen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a max/min value as part of the `yAxis` or `xAxis` options.

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: [0, 1, 2, 3]
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    min: 0,
    max: 40,
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'A',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40],
      type: 'line'
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      data: [1, 10, 100, 1000],
      type: 'line'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: I can, but then I'd need to do some smart calculations to work out where the max should be - echarts antomagically scales the y axis not only by the min/max values of all the data series, but also so the numbers on the axis are set to an appropriate tick (documentation here: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#yAxis.max "It will be automatically computed to make sure axis tick is equally distributed when not set."

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, then you just need to add another axis and attach each series to each axis. This way you can ignore other series within the same axis.

Comment: Will this just scale the second axis so data B also fits on the graph area?